# How can I argue about a migration that I don't agree with?

Tags: discussion, comments, migration

Suppose someone migrates your question to another site, and you believe the question was misunderstood. The other site closes it down since it also doesn't fit. What is the most appropriate course of action?

- It's impossible to comment upon the question, since it is closed.
- It's probably impolite to post again the same question, even if slightly altered.

Comment: The question under discussion is this one [ http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/956/what-is-the-best-non-metaphysical-argumentation-against-the-dust-theory-closed ]

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question presented here, rather than the specific scenario (which seems to have been amended).

The general approach to questioning a migration is to **open a Meta question on the topic**. Basically, provide a link to the question that was migrated, explain why you don't think it should have been migrated, and the ensuing discussion will help determine whether the migration was wrong and should be undone, or if it was correct.

You can comment on closed questions, and that is generally the primary method for opposing closures (unless the particular topic is big enough to warrant a Meta post). However, in the case of migration, the question becomes locked in addition to closed, and this *does* prevent commenting. It's still reversible - a moderator can clear the migration history and unlock the question. Which, to that point, if consensus shows that the question should be reopened, but a moderator hasn't been a part of the exchange, don't be afraid to flag for moderator attention in order to ping someone who can fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

That was my mistake -- I read the question too quickly. It seemed to me you were asking about Egan's stories and I apologize.

That said, I have backed out the migration and closed the question -- your formulation opens general debate rather than posing an answerable question. Please feel free to ask further questions, and to reformulate this one in different terms. Keep in mind Philosophy.SE is a Q&A community and not a philosophy forum, so try to ask answerable questions rather than proposing a topic of discussion.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your reply. I still think that this poses a nice meta-question (i.e., commenting upon a migrated question which leaves no trail in the original forum).

Comment: Maybe for metaSO? But there's always a trail for the mods to follow if they wish.

Comment: BTW, can one edit the post and try to reformulate the question after being closed, or should one create a new question?

Comment: Yes! You are absolutely encouraged to reformulate closed questions into shape. Closing isn't a punishment and isn't (necessarily) permanent.

Comment: The fact that a closed question can be commented upon is great. Maybe questions should be closed before they are migrated? That would seem to provide a solution for this meta-question.

Comment: Not a bad point. Again, I apologize for the hasty reading. I will definitely be more careful about migrations in the future.

Comment: No problem. You were right that the question was not being formulated correctly.

Comment: From the point of view of someone who is just now paying attention, I think you handled this very well. And I'm happy that you revamped your question.

Comment: The history on the linked question doesn't show that it was migrated anywhere. Just closed, first as "off topic", then as "not constructive". Where did you migrate it originally?

Comment: Sci-fi and fantasy